# URL endpoint with HTML

Tags: url-rewriting, endpoints

I'm using WordPress endpoints to render another template on a post page. How can I add *.html* to the end of the URL that using the endpoint?

### Example:

Normal URL: **example.com/angry-birds**

Normal URL with endpoint: **example.com/angry-birds/play**

**Here are the results I'm trying to achieve:**

`example.com/angry-birds.html` and `example.com/angry-birds/play.html`

Comment: I haven't tried this myself so it is a comment not an answer: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/page-permalinks-html-ending?replies=4#post-673065

Comment: @s_ha_dum it doesn't support for endpoints.